# Django - Cannot assign "'dortmund'": "Administrator.asoc_name" must be a "Association" instance

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-views

**Edit description:**

I want to register an admin with the `association_id` in the `Administrator` table to avoid null_value.

Is there something i'm missing?

Still a newbie so appreciate your help, folks!

**EDIT: forgot to insert right ForeginKeys**

admin\models.py

```
class Administrator(AbstractUser):
    ...
    association= models.ForeignKey(Association)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Administrator'
```

member\models.py

```
from pl.admin.models import Administrator


class Association(models.Model):
    asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    member_no = models.ForeignKey(Member)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Association'
```

---

forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
     association_choices = [(i['pk'], i['asoc_name'])
                       for i in Association.objects.values('asoc_name', 'pk')]
     association = forms.ChoiceField(choices=association_choices,
                                   widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
                                   required=True)
     ...


    class Meta:
        model = Administrator
        fields = [..., 'association', ...]
```

---

views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if not form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'admin/signup.html',
                          {'form': form})

        else:
            ...
            asoc_pk = form.cleaned_data.get('association')
            asoc = Association.objects.get(pk=asoc_pk)
            ...
            Administrator.objects.create_user(...
                                              association=asoc,    
                                              ...)
            user = authenticate(...
                                association=asoc,
                                ...)
            return redirect('/')

    else:
        return render(request, 'admin/signup.html',
                      {'form': SignUpForm()})
```

Comment: I was mistaken. I was not looking closely to the `association_choices`. That should contain the Association, not only its name. But I am not familiar with this usage of `forms.ChoiceField`, so maybe I am still overlooking something.

Comment: No problem, i really appreciate your effort for trying to help =D